# Create CGRect with short way - swift

Tags: swift, cgrect

When I created CGRect in Objective-c and I didn't want to set each value, I created in this way:

```
 (CGRect){CGPointMake(0, 0), [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size}
```

Do you know a similar way in swift?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Swift adds a special initializer to `CGRect` that does just that.

```
let rect = CGRect(
    origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
    size: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
)
```

For Swift 3.0 you would do this...

```
let rect = CGRect(
    origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
    size: UIScreen.main.bounds.size
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way for `0,0`

```
let rect = CGRect(
    origin: CGPointZero,
    size: UIScreen.main.bounds.size
)
```

Comment: Swift 3 and above: use CGPoint.zero

Answer (score 0):

- swift5

`let rect = UIScreen.main.bounds`